# Exclude specific dependency from only one flavor

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I have many flavors (5 for example) and all of them uses common dependency.

I know how to compile library only for one flavor (flavorImplementation "org.sample:lib:1.0").
But now I need exclude this dependency for one of flavors. I've overrode dependency packages with stubs in flavor, but dependency still compiles for this flavor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all*exclude group:'groupId',module:'moduleId',you can specify only exclude dependency for one flavor like this:

```
configurations {
      ...
      flavorImplementation.exclude group:'groupId',module:'moduleId' 
}
```

Please replace `flavor` to your flavorName, and also replace the `groupId` and `moduleId`.